# Need Help Creating Form Elements Based On Click via JavaScript and JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, input, append

I'm pretty new to web programming and I am trying to simply add text fields to a certain form based upon clicking a previous text field. The html page will start with one field and will grow with text fields based upon clicking any previous field. This is via client-side JavaScript.

However, it seems like the code isn't working and I'm not getting anywhere. All that shows up is one text field regulated by the HTML and the click event is outputting anything. You can ignore the styling for right now.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>This is just a test</title>
<script type="text/javascript"  src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js">
$(document).ready(function(){
var inival = 0;
function addTextBox()
{
    var newArea = add_New_Element();
    var htcontents = "<input type='text' name='textbx[]'/>";
    document.getElementById(newArea).innerHTML = htcontents; // You can any other elements in place of 'htcontents' 
}
function add_New_Element() 
{
inival=inival+1; // Increment element number by 1
var ni = document.getElementById('area');
var newdiv = document.createElement('div'); // Create dynamic element
var divIdName = 'my'+inival+'Div';
newdiv.setAttribute('id',divIdName);
ni.appendChild(newdiv);
return divIdName;
}
  $("input").click(function(){
    addTextBox();
  });
});
</script>
<body>
<div>
<form id="mainform" action="execute.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="textbx[]"/>
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can replace your entire solution with this:

```
$("input").click(function() {
    $(this).after($(this).clone(true)); 
    $(this).after("<br />");
});
```

[**Demo.**](http://jsfiddle.net/3YayZ/)

I would prefer to use [`.delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) and not bother cloning the event handlers:

```
$("#myForm").delegate("input", "click", function() {
    $(this).after($(this).clone()); 
    $(this).after("<br />");
});
```

[**Demo.**](http://jsfiddle.net/tPSs6/)

Comment: @user859434 - You're welcome :) Just a thing, it would be better for you to actually understand where/why your code is broken (see the other answers) rather than simply replacing your with the solution I posted; you'll benefit greatly from it.

Comment: Oh wow, I made an error referencing the google-hosted jquery library...hence why jquery events wouldn't work.

Comment: Just another quick question, when I send this data on these fields, they get posted to execute.php which (for right now) simply has "print_r($_POST["textbx[]"]);" in order to print the array out; however, this doesn't print anything.

Comment: @user859434 - You just need `print_r($_POST["textbx"]);` to access the textbx array.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
var ni = document.getElementById('area');
```

will set `ni` to `null`, because you don't have any elements with an Id of 'area'. Which means later in the function when you try to say:

```
ni.appendChild(newdiv);
```

it won't work.

Incidentally, why are you creating the extra div elements to hold the new inputs? Why not just add input elements directly?

Answer (score 0):

first you don't have any tag with id `area` so it will generate error when trying get it

I think you do it with hard way check this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/p2yq2/) it more simple than what you do